# Javascript's syntactic sugar for accessing object properties

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, properties

I have a 'result' object that I'd like to pool the value of these nested properties.

Is there an elegant way to assign the values of these two properties **if they exist** and throw and error otherwise? I find myself writing some long code for doing such a simple operation.

Thanks

```
host: result["ServerCA"]["_"],
database: result["DBId"]["_"]
```

### EDIT1 - more information

My code constructs an object that has the two properties `host` and `database`.
The `result` object is a JSON containing some information.
I can't guarantee that the JSON will actually contain these two properties `_` under `ServerCA` and `_` under `DBId`. As a matter of fact, I can't be sure that `ServerCA` and `DBId` will be defined in the `result` object.

So I'm trying to validate that these properties exist, and assign their value to my own object's two properties `host` and `database`.

How can I write this in the simplest way instead of writing 2 double IF statements?

Thanks...

Comment: You can use the dot convention like `result.ServerCA._` but I doubt that it makes it any simpler.

Comment: maybe you add an example object

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Doesn't your current code already do what you ask?

Comment: What actually is possibly not defined? `result.ServerCA`? Or `result.ServerCA._`? or `host`? In your current code, if  `result.ServerCA` doesn't exist, trying to read the value of `result.ServerCA._` will throw an error.

Comment: Teemu nothing is guaranteed to be defined. 
I've edited my question, now it has more information.

Sorry

Comment: @johni Well, there are some [relatively simple ways](https://jsfiddle.net/s7p58yu4/1/), but you wouldn't have good control over error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function to do this, for example:

```
function getOrThrow(obj, keys) {
    return keys.reduce(function(result, key) {
        if (!(typeof result === 'object') || !(key in result)) {
            throw new Error("property " + key + " does not exists");
        }
        return result[key];
    }, obj);
}

var result = {
    ServerCA: {
        _: "whatever"
    }
};

console.log(getOrThrow(result, ["ServerCA", "_"])); // whatever
console.log(getOrThrow(result, ["ServerCA", "_", "other"])); // throws error
```